# Any way to see the order in which the .js are loaded using the browser (chrome or firefox)?

Tags: javascript, browser

any way to see the order in which .js are loaded using the browser (chrome or firefox)?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug should show you the order of the JS files that are being loaded, it will also show details such as the response headers, time taken to download etc. It works as a native plugin for FF, there is also a lite version for Chrome but I don't think this can track JS files.

http://getfirebug.com/

For Chrome the Developer Tools should show the scripts that are being loaded, their order, time etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

`ctrl-shift-j` in chrome, click resources